# Flink: Compute only at the end of a session window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an [AggregateFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction) which computes an average over a sequence of events in a [WindowedStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/WindowedStream.html).
The caveat here is that the average needs to be computed over event pairs which can arrive out of order (or not at all).

In other words, I need to sort the data before the computation because the sequence is important.

I can do this with [getResult](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.html#getResult-ACC-) API but this function is called on every event in the window, which doesn't make sense performance wise.
I could also do this with [flink-cep](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html), but I'd like to avoid it for the same reason.

Ideally, I'd like to only compute the average at the very end (where I can sort the data once), when the window is closed.

Is there some sort of handler for this? The closest thing I found was [triggers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers), but there is no method for the closing of the window.

Thanks

**Edit:**
I ended up using [ProcessWindowFunction with Incremental Aggregation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction-with-incremental-aggregation)

> A ProcessWindowFunction can be combined with either a ReduceFunction,
>   an AggregateFunction, or a FoldFunction to incrementally aggregate
>   elements as they arrive in the window. When the window is closed, the
>   ProcessWindowFunction will be provided with the aggregated result.
>   This allows it to incrementally compute windows while having access to
>   the additional window meta information of the ProcessWindowFunction.

Comment: With streaming data, what does "at the very end" mean?

Comment: @kkrugler at the end of the window, not the end of the stream. This is a keyed window, so on each "window end".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I hadn't seen a mention of time here, so I was worried you had some other trigger in mind for defining the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an AggregateFunction, you can use a [ProcessWindowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction) without incremental aggregation. This function will be called when the window is triggered, and will be passed an Iterable containing the window's contents, and a Collector you can use to emit results.

When the ProcessWindowFunction is called you can sort the contents, and produce whatever output you want.